# HTML values inside CSS3 content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to place year numbers into circular forms along the vertical timeline.
My initial idea is to use CSS content and maybe by using javascript to extract some data proprety from HTML, something like year="1958" and place it into circle. How to do that? Is it possible to reposition that year number so it fits perfectly into the circle? HTML and CSS follows. Down below there is a link to the same codepen.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
    /* Set a background color */
    body {
      background-color: #181818;
      font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
      line-height:1.6;
      font-weight:500;
      text-align:left;
    }
    
    /* The actual timeline (the vertical ruler) */
    .timeline {
      position: relative;
      max-width: 1200px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .year1958 {
      content: '1958';
      
    }
    
    /* The actual timeline (the vertical ruler) */
    .timeline::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: 1px;
      background-color: #b69472;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -3px;
    }
    
    /* Container around content */
    .container {
      padding: 10px 40px;
      position: relative;
      background-color: inherit;
      width: 50%;
    }
    
    /* The circles on the timeline */
    .container::after {
      color: #b69472;
      margin:px;
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 66px;
      height: 66px;
      right: -33px;
      background-color: #181818;
      border-color: #b69472;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width:1px;
      top: 15px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .circlecontainer {
      color: #b69472;
      margin:px;
      content: "XXXX";
      position: absolute;
      width: 66px;
      height: 66px;
      right: -33px;
      background-color: #181818;
      border-color: #b69472;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width:1px;
      top: 15px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    /* Place the container to the left */
    .left {
      left: 0;
      text-align:right;
    }
    
    /* Place the container to the right */
    .right {
      left: 50%;
    }
    
    /* Fix the circle for containers on the right side */
    .right::after {
      left: -36px;
    }
    
    /* The actual content */
    .content {
      color:#b69472;
      padding: 20px 30px;
      background-color: #181818;
      position: relative;
      border-radius: 6px;
    }
    
    .contentboxr {
      color:#b69472;
      padding: 20px 30px;
      background-color: #181818;
      position: relative;
      border-style: solid;
      border-left: 1px;
      border-left-color:#181818;
      border-width:1px;
      left:-43px;
      z-index:5;
    }
    
    .containerbox {
      padding: 10px 40px;
      position: relative;
      background-color: inherit;
      width: 50%;
    }
    
    .contentboxr::after {
      display: none !important;
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    
    /* Media queries - Responsive timeline on screens less than 600px wide */
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    /* Place the timelime to the left */
      .timeline::after {
        left: 51px;
      }
    
    /* Full-width containers */
      .container {
        width: 100%;
        padding-left: 70px;
        padding-right: 25px;
      }
      .contentboxr {
      color:#b69472;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      background-color: #181818;
      position: relative;
      border-style: solid;
      border-left: 0px;
      border-left-color:#181818;
      border-right: 0px;
      border-right-color:#181818;
      width:280%;
    }
    
    /* Make sure that all arrows are pointing leftwards */
      .container::before {
        left: 60px;
        border: medium solid white;
        border-width: 10px 10px 10px 0;
        border-color: transparent white transparent transparent;
      }
    
    /* Make sure all circles are at the same spot */
      .left::after, .right::after {
        left: 15px;
      }
    
    /* Make all right containers behave like the left ones */
      .right {
        left: 0%;
        text-align:left;
      }
      .left {
        text-align:left;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
      <div class="container left">
        <div class="content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container right">
        <div class="content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="container left">
        <div class="content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum.... LEFT</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="containerbox right" yearyear="1234">
        <div class="contentboxr">
          <h3 style="line-height:1.8;"><em>Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum...</em></h3>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="container left">
        <div class="content">
          <h2>2017</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

https://codepen.io/drol/pen/oVbKva

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom "data" attributes on the Circle  html element + the css3 attr function in css.

Here is an example:

```css
p:before {
  content:attr(data-foo) " ";
}
```

```html
<p data-foo="Hello">World</p>
```

Comment: Im not sure how to utilize this in mentioned svenario where circle element is just css “::after” element to predcessor

Comment: And not sure I can stylize content only. Don’t know how

Comment: you can use a :before Element for the content and :after Element for styling / positioning etc